# Git push: The object is 12311134 byte, which is greater than the 1048576 byte limit for objects in this repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

When attempting to push some commits made in local environment up to Azure DevOps Repos[origin] I get error:

**The object is 12311134 byte, which is greater than the 1048576 byte limit for objects in this repository**

I'm trying this by runnning command git push origin  to push only that branch up into the origin. Where is this limit set on my repository?
- I'm new to objects in git, so why is my push failing to go through? 
- Is there a way to change it or is this set by default?
- What could I be doing wrong? Does it has to do with the size of my files?

`git push origin <nameOfBranch>`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `Azure DevOps` repos have a 1MB size limit for any file (which is reasonable to keep the repo more usable)

To manage larger files than that, youshould use [Git LFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=azure-devops#use-git-large-file-storage-lfs)

It seems that git lfs [supported and free for Azure DevOps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-git-lfs-on-all-vso-git-repos/) repos since 2015 with some limitations (e.g by @4c74356b41: can not use ssh with LFS).

Altough is recommended to use git lfs for big files, you could also configure max file size settings in [Repository Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops#maximum-file-size)

Comment: well, fully supported is a bit of an overstatement. you cant use ssh to work with repo with git lft

Comment: this still occurred when pushing a *repo* that was over 1MB, but with no single file over the 1MB limit. I had to increase the "file size limit" within Azure DevOps repo settings in order to push to remote since it seemed like it was counting the entire repo size in the 1MB limit restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps repos are set to unlimited file size by default. Someone in my organization may have changed it accidentally by going to Project settings > Repositories page, choose the repo -> Options tab -> Maximum file size. Just had to change it to a larger size limit [unlimited]

[image: Maximum file size in Azure Repos]

Comment: this error still occurred for me when pushing a **repo** that was over 1MB, but with no single file over the 1MB limit. I had to increase the "file size limit" within Azure DevOps repo settings in order to push to remote since it seemed like it was counting the entire repo size in the 1MB limit restriction.