# Git push always fails to remote repository

Tags: git, git-push, rider

While working on certain codebase, I accidently set the incorrect origin and pulled. I removed all those files pulled form incorrect repository and fixed the origin. However after that I'm unable to push my changes even to the correct repository and I get this message after my push is rejected:

> Push failed Total 97 (delta 70), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
> remote unpack failed: error The blob object
> ce9756fb503d04fe64f108e6542f5fb7f6342ca9 was rejected: VS403658: The
> object will increase this repository size by 30251229 bytes (the limit
> is 10485760 bytes). remote: The blob object
> ce9756fb503d04fe64f108e6542f5fb7f6342ca9 was rejected: VS403658: The
> object will increase this repository size by 30251229 bytes (the limit
> is 10485760 bytes). send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading
> sideband packet the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I'm using rider C#. Even from the command line same thing happens. I checked all the commits to make sure that it does not contain any suspicious file. All the commits contain regular files. This branch contains 7 commits with 14 files.

*What does this error mean and How can I fix it?*

Comment: I don't know much about Rider but this error means there are limits for file size and you should use Git LFS.

Comment: the problem is none of the files is more than 1kb. so total payload is 14kb or less of 7 commits. what exactly is it trying to push that is not even available in 7 commits?

Comment: The other software you're using (not *your* Git software, the software at the remote Git, which is why each message here is prefixed with `remote:`, it's coming *from* the remote: some software being run on behalf of the Git software on the remote) *is* claiming that you have some very large file(s) in some of the commit(s) you're sending. You have to convince that software that things are OK. How you do that is up to, well, that software.

Comment: that other software is Azure!

Comment: There are some other questions with the Azure for the same situation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500425/git-push-the-object-is-12311134-byte-which-is-greater-than-the-1048576-byte-li

Git LFS is recommended.